# GCC allowing arrays to be initialized with variable length

Tags: c, gcc, variable-length-array

GCC compiles the following function

```
void f(int i)
{
    int a[i];
}
```

I was under the impression that you can only initialize arrays with constant length.  Is this supposed to compile, and will it do what I expect it to?

Answer (score 2):

C99 added variable length arrays. And `gcc` adds this to c89 as an extension with  `-std=gnu89` option (the default with `gcc`).

In the latest C Standard, C11, variable length arrays support is marked as optional.

Comment: Does the array get put on the stack or somewhere in the heap using malloc?

Comment: @user1887231 variable length arrays can only be declared at block scope and with automatic storage duration, so practically yes they are usually stored in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

VLA's are allowed in C99. GCC extention allows it to compile in C89 mode.